# AJAX not posting data to text file via PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, forms

I have a form and I want to save the entries in a text file on the server when a submission is done.

The jquery I'm using is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
localStorage.clear();

$("form").on("submit", function() {
    if(window.localStorage!==undefined) {
        var fields = $(this).serialize();

        localStorage.setItem("eloqua-fields", JSON.stringify( fields ));
        alert("Stored Succesfully");
        $(this).find("input[type=text]").val("");
        alert("Now Passing stored data to Server through AJAX jQuery");
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "backend.php",
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           data: {data: fields},
           success: function(data) {
              $('#output').html(data);
           }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Storage Failed. Try refreshing");
    }
});
});
```

And the PHP I'm using is:

```
 <h1>Below is the data retrieved from SERVER</h1>
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago'); // CDT
    echo '<h2>Server Timezone : ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '</h2>';
    $current_date = date('d/m/Y == H:i:s ');
    print "<h2>Server Time : " . $current_date . "</h2>";
    $dataObject = $_POST['data'];
    $json = json_decode($dataObject);
    echo $json;
    file_put_contents('your_data.txt', $json);
?>
```

You can see the live version of the form here: http://hackingarticles.com/marketer/

The problem is that my code is not posting any data to http://hackingarticles.com/marketer/your_data.txt

I've been trying to solve this for so long but it's just not working for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: What do you get if you `echo $dataObject` ?

Comment: Make sure your .txt file has the correct permissions set, try with the full path to the .txt file, turn on error reporting to see if any notices / errors are triggered

Comment: @Archer - Do you mean, echo it in the PHP file?

Comment: @tlenss - I don't see any errors and the permission is 777 for now.

Comment: @SackboyB Yes.  It's very rudimentary and basic debugging.  There's something wrong in there so start dumping things out so you can check what's going on.  If you've got an empty text file (which the url suggests) then it's most likely the data that's at fault, not writing the file.

Comment: @Archer - Right. The txt file is created just fine so there's something wrong with the data. See my updated PHP code above to see echo usage but I can't see anything here: hackingarticles.com/marketer/backend.php

Comment: That works fine for me.  Obviously if you just hit the url then you're not passing any post data to echo, so I used a rest client to post something and it echoed my data.

Comment: @Archer - Then why is it not posting data to http://hackingarticles.com/marketer/your_data.txt ?

Comment: Can you change it to `echo $json` instead, so we can see what happens after it attempts to parse it?

Comment: @Archer - Just did that and I receive a PHP error: [28-Jan-2014 06:08:30 America/Chicago] PHP Notice: Undefined index: data in /home4/hackinga/public_html/marketer/backend.php on line 7 See my full HTML here: jsbin.com/urUCIwaH/1/edit and PHP here: jsbin.com/olOXOsiK/1/edit

Comment: @Archer - Looks like stackoverflow went down there for a while. Just realised how little I know about anything :P

Comment: That's a problem with decoding the data then, and I'm afraid I'm no php expert.  At least you've narrowed down where the issue is.  You'll need someone that's a lot more familiar with it than me.  I hope it's at least helped a little so far - good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP:

```
<h1>Below is the data retrieved from SERVER</h1>
<?php
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago'); // CDT
        echo '<h2>Server Timezone : ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '</h2>';
        $current_date = date('d/m/Y == H:i:s ');
        print "<h2>Server Time : " . $current_date . "</h2>";

        $dataObject = $_POST; //Fetching all posts

        echo "<pre>"; //making the dump look nice in html.
        var_dump($dataObject);
        echo "</pre>";

            //Writes it as json to the file, you can transform it any way you want
        $json = json_encode($dataObject);
        file_put_contents('your_data.txt', $json);
?>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    localStorage.clear();

    $("form").on("submit", function() {
        if(window.localStorage!==undefined) {
            var fields = $(this).serialize();

            localStorage.setItem("eloqua-fields", JSON.stringify( fields ));
            alert("Stored Succesfully");
            $(this).find("input[type=text]").val("");
            alert("Now Passing stored data to Server through AJAX jQuery");
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "backend.php",         
               data: fields,
               success: function(data) {
                  $('#output').html(data);
               }
            });
        } else {
            alert("Storage Failed. Try refreshing");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: 755 for the directory and files

Comment: Did you mean like this: http://jsbin.com/olOXOsiK/2/edit It's throwing an error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home4/hackinga/public_html/marketer/backend.php on line 7

Comment: Do not decode it as json as its NOT json. Delete that decoding. For debugging. Try var_dump($_POST); to see that the $_POST actually contains something.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `contentType` property in the ajax request, like, `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`. I already have been through this problem (not sending any data to the server) and that solved my problem